# Speakers Suddently Don't Work, Only Headphones Work

Tags: 12.04, sound, speakers

When I go to "system settings" then "sound" it doesn't even recognize that there are speakers, it only shows options for headphones. The speakers/headphones worked just fine a week ago. I think maybe since doing an update it got messed up? Anyway, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since the headphone is working fine then this should NOT be driver issue.
Ensure that volume settings are fine. Try to boot from ubuntu live CD if possible and check sound works fine.